# Add button in an item of a List Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

there's a way to add a button or a link on the right side of the items of a List Card on Teams? Similar to this image for illustration.

[list card example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU4Bn.png)

Some of my users are complaining that the UX of this component could not make clear that it is a clickable card.
Any thoughts on adding a button or similar to the card items?

Comment: Please follow this doc(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seems to be any way to add a button or a link on the right side of the items of a List Card on Teams.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'm new in theses technologies and needed to make sure it wasn't really possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a custom bot using Bot Framework, you can try AdaptiveCards instead.
It can't scroll like ListCard, but you can use some kind of pagination if it suits your needs.

Check on this:
https://adaptivecards.io/samples/